# What does it mean for a vector to be "reduced" with respect to a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an inner product space with some chosen (not orthogonal in general) basis, $v \in V$ an arbitrary vector, and $U \subset V$ a subspace. Let's further suppose that $U$ is represented by a matrix (which I will also denote $U$) whose columns for a basis in terms of the chosen basis for $V$.

If $v \in U$, then we can write $v = Uw$ for some $w$. If it is not, I have seen the terminology that one can "reduce" $v$ with respect to $U$, that is, write $v = Uw + v'$. What exactly are the conditions on $v'$ that makes this representation "reduced"? Obviously $v'$ should be zero if $v \in U$, but I'm not sure what the requirements are if it is not.

Here are a few possibilities:

1. We're in an inner product space, so take the difference of $v$ with its orthogonal projection onto $U$ (although we might not already have an orthogonal basis for $U$, and because my application is in computing, I'd prefer not to do this).
2. Extend the basis for $U$ to a basis $U'$ for $V$ in some "minimal" way, and compute $v=U'w$, splitting up $w$ appropriately afterward.
3. Since we are in a normed vector space, require some sort of norm minimization on $v'$

EDIT: my main question is: how does one compute this reduction? For the sake of full disclosure, the place I'm seeing this notation is in [this paper of Gunnar Carlsson](http://comptop.stanford.edu/u/preprints/zigzags-socg-final.pdf), first paragraph of the second page of section 4. (Algorithm), "case $f_i$".

Comment: I'd guess 1. and 3. (which are equivalent).  "Reduction" can mean "make shorter" as in "lattice basis reduction algorithm".